# Writing into stdin with subprocess

Tags: python, linux

I have the following C Program

```
#include <stdio.h>


int main()
{

    char a[200];
    a[199] = 0;


    printf("Enter some input ->\n");
    scanf("%s"  ,a);

    printf ("\nInput was %s\n", a);

    return 0;
}
```

and I'm trying to write some input into it the following way:

```
from subprocess import *
a = Popen(["my_prog.elf", stdin=PIPE) 
a.stdin.write("MyInput")
```

yet this doesn't appear to work.... any ideas how to fix this?

** edit **

does anyone have any clue why `a.stdin.flush()` wont work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`scanf`reads one whole line, until it reads the new line character `\n`, so you have to send this, too:

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE
a = Popen(["my_prog.elf"], stdin=PIPE) 
a.stdin.write("MyInput\n")
```

`flush` is only needed, if your output stream (`stdin`) is buffered (which pipes are not, by default). Even then, you need `\n` to terminate the line.

Comment: ** edit ** wow.... this apparently worked for some reason............. any idea why flush didn't work and this did?

Comment: Work's for me. What have you done exactly and who do you know, it doesn't work?

Comment: Basically im writing into stdin and having prints of what I wrote with stdin, so when trying to use flush it failed unfortunately..... @Daniel

Comment: Well, actually, `scanf("%s" ...)` reads one whole line, simply because that's how a "string" is defined to `scanf`. Technically, it would be more correct to say that `scanf` reads up until the first character that is incompatible with the data type specified by the format flags it's currently processing - e.g. it would stop at the first non-decimal-digit for `%d`...